# I feel very strange because this proof doesn't use base case at all. Please help me to get rid of this strange feeling.

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I feel very strange because this proof doesn't use base case at all.
So, this proof doesn't need base case at all.
Please help me to get rid of this strange feeling.

[image]

Comment: But it *is* using and proving the base case: "*the theorem is ... true for groups having a single element*". That it happens to be "*vacuously true*" doesn't change the fact that it is *true* in the first place, it just preempts the question of "*why is it true*".

Comment: Try to read through the inductive step while assuming $G$ has order $2$, and assuming the base case of order $1$ is true. If you can see that the proof works in that case, then hopefully it can get rid of your doubt.

Comment: Another way to think of the proof, is that all prime orders (and $1$) are base cases, and then the induction is done on non-prime orders.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Milten Thank you very much for your comments.